# Angular custom directive with filter in attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I would like make angular directive where I use filter on data which are passed as argument.

So something like this:

`<div class="my-module" data="a in array | orFilter:filter"></div>`

Where "data" is attribute of directive "my-module".
I looked into ngRepeat source, but they parse ng-repeat argument and then they evaluate them. I can't use ng-repeat because I'm creating new instance of object (Marker for map) from data parameter.

Is it realy so hard? Is possible do this in custom directive and how?

Small example what i want: http://jsfiddle.net/PjRAr/1/

**EDIT**

I'm trying extend this [map wrapper](https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/blob/master/src/angular-google-maps.js) to render filtered markers.

My potencional solution is holding copy of all markers and visible markers. Add $watch to filter and when filter was changed call `$scope.markers = $scope.$eval("allMarkers | orFilter:filter");`.

With this solution we need hold two copy of all markers (~500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when I use one-way binding i got empty array in $watch (i think it's trying evaluate in local scope [removed "data" from directive scope for one way binding]. When i use two way binding [in directive scope is {data: "=data"}] i got error "Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations" (it's common error for filtering in angular).

So my solution:

Directive:

```
...
scope: {
  data: "=data"
}
...
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  ...
  scope.$watch("data", function (newValue) {
    angular.forEach(newValue, function (v, i) {
      model.add(v);
    }
  }
}
...
```

Controller:

```
  ...
  $scope.filter = { a:true, b:false, ... };
  $scope.all = [..data..];
  $scope.visible = [..data..];    

  $scope.$watch("filter", function(newValue) {    
    $scope.visible = $scope.$eval("all | orFilter:filter"); 
  }, true);
  ...
```

HTML:

```
<div my-module data="visible"></div>
```

Thank you very much guys, you're help me so much. I'm learned many new things about angular binding.

Answer (score 3):

You can `$eval` the filter expression.

in your directive link function:

```
elem.text( scope.$eval( attrs.data ).join(', ') );
```

in your template:

```
<div my-directive data="['Hello', 'xxx', 'World'] | filter:'o'"></div>
```

and the directive renders (by filtering-out 'xxx') to:

```
Hello, World
```

***EDIT***:

If the values are dynamic, you can of course do:

```
scope.$watch( attrs.data, function( arr ) {
  elem.text( arr.join(', ') );
});
```

I do not think you can avoid having `$watch`, though.

Comment: Nice solution but not for me. At first it needs hard coded array in data attribute and filter parameter (because scope visibility). Next I need $watch data attribute for change.

Comment: Your solution is so close but i have classic problem with "Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations", trying add $$hash to collection but still nothing. [fiddle with model](http://jsfiddle.net/sSHdT/4/)

Comment: I think two-way binding between parent scope and the directive causing it.  If you use `attrs.data` approach (which is one-way binding), the problem should not occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing a few things.  I'm not sure why you don't want to use `ng-repeat`, that's what it's made for.  Because you isolate the scope you don't have access to the parent scope.  The `'='` binding tries to bind your isolated scope data attribute to the parent scope's model called what is in the attribute, but you can't bind to something that has been filtered.  If you don't want to repeat the div with the attributes, put them on your own element, it just creates the content...

Here's a fiddle showing both using ng-repeat.  You can see the binding is 2-way, it adds an `updated: true` property.

[(FIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/sSHdT/3/)

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        element.append('<p>a: ' + scope.data.a + ', b: ' + scope.data.b);
        scope.data.updated = true;
    }
```

Comment: ng-repeat is used (by me) to visualise item using html or similar. I can't show data directly. I have model for comunication with third party renderer where i can put only objects with data. Something like this [fiddle with model](http://jsfiddle.net/sSHdT/4/).

Comment: Not sure if a directive is the best way to do that, what's the point of having it in your HTML instead of just using javascript?

Comment: Look at my edit of question. I'm trying extend map wrapper to render filtered markers. I solved it with horrible hack, but it's working for now. Thank you for your help.